# Unity: how to resolve class through base interface

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

Here is my repository class:

```
public interface IMyRepository : IRepository<IMyEntity>{}

public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
...
}
```

Here is way to register it:

```
container.Register<IMyRepository, MyRepository >();
```

Here is the way how I want to get repository resolved:

```
IRepository<IMyEntity> repository = container.Resolve<IRepository<IMyEntity>>();
```

Attempt to resolve repository in this ways give an error:

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "CMCore.Repository.IRepository`1[CMCore.Data.ICmCoreLog]", name = "(none)".
>   Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>
> ### Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, IRepository`1[IMyEntity], is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
>
> At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving IRepository`1[IMyEntity],(none)

What is wrong in my approach? What is a proper way to achieve mentioned functionality?

Thanks a lot!

P.S. Sometime I want to resolve my class through the IMyRepository, sometime through IRepository. Should I register class twice?

Comment: Why do you need this extra `IMyRepository` interface?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question :-)

Comment: Sorry, :) Some of specialized repositories have own methods (for example, GetMyEntityBySomeCriterias) they encapsulate querying logic... trying to answer your question I got, that actually, I could remove usage of IMyRepository with IRepository<IMyEntity>. This requires some efforts, but... is still doable... Do you think I need to go this way? Probably you would better create an answer...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
container.RegisterType<IRepository<IMyEntity>, MyRepository>();
```

instead. Unity, by design, only does one level of type mapping. It's only going to look for a mapping from the type you ask, it doesn't chase down inheritance trees.

If you want it to be available both a IRepository or as IMyRepository, then just register it twice:

```
container.RegisterType<IRepository<IMyEntity>, MyRepository>()
    .RegisterType<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
```

Comment: Thanks, it's too sorry that Unity doesn't support mapping taking inheritance into account.

Comment: What does "taking inheritance into account" actually mean? We'd have to define it, implement it (which could easily result in N^2 or worse resolve times as we wander the inheritance graph), document it, and then answer all the people who want a different definition then the one we built. At least this way things are simple, easy to understand, and, as you can see, easy to work around if you want a different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
IMyRepository repository = container.Resolve<IMyRepository>();
```